# how to create custom login registration application laravel without using auth ,by creating own controller model

Tags: laravel, authorization

I am new in laravel. I have installed laravel 5.4. I have  installed laravel inbuild auth. but I want to create own login &  registration with two user type . one is customer and another is for admin with different functionalities for two user types.  using custom controller,model route without using auth.

Comment: Why bother? Have 1 login and register system and then have a `userLevel` within the `users` table that then redirects the admin to admin panel and the user to the user panel?

Comment: if you really don't want to use auth, laracasts has an episode or two on doing it yourself in the laravel from scratch series

Comment: @Thijs, I believe they still use the auth functions..

Comment: they don't use make:auth, they do use the Auth class, but not using Auth and trying to do security yourself is really hard if you want to do it right

Comment: Uhm yes they do? **Rapid Authentication and Configuration** but I agree with you. Why reinvent the wheel @Dip Sekhar?

Comment: @Option Associating With Users and Associating With Users: Part 2

Comment: Because I dont want to use migrate tables like User & its  auto fields like id,timestamps, I have the Db connection of Sql server. I want to store the session using redis database & other further db interactions in Sql server. so I want to continue the website in both db.